# Issue attaching file to MS Graph email in Angular 9

Tags: angular, graph, base64, email-attachments

I'm adding file attachment functionality to an Angular 9 web app but have run into an issue.

The MS Graph API reference says that any file should be based64 encoded before being used and I've done this but I get the following error

> {"error":{"code":"RequestBodyRead","message":"Cannot convert the
> literal 'data:application/pdf;base64,JV.....' to the expected type
> 'Edm.Binary'."}}

Here's my code;

```
  getBase64(file: File) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
      reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
    });
  }

async sendEmail(toEmail: string, subject: string, message: string, fileAttachment: File): Promise<any> {

    this.getBase64(fileAttachment).then(
      async data => {
        // console.log(data)

        try {
          const sendMail = {
            message: {
              subject: subject,
              body: {
                contentType: 'HTML',
                content: message
              },
              toRecipients: [
                {
                  emailAddress: {
                    address: toEmail
                  }
                }
              ],
              attachments: [
                {
                  "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
                  "name": fileAttachment.name,
                  "contentType": fileAttachment.type.toString,
                  "contentBytes": data
                }
              ]
            }
          };

          let res = await this.client.api('/me/sendMail').post(sendMail);

          return res;
        } catch (error) {
          this.handleError(error);
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

If anyone can help I'd greatly appreciate it. I've been working on this for some time now and not been able to solve the issue.

Many thanks,

Mark.

UPDATE:

Using the MS Graph Explorer to send an email I was able to determine the cause of the issue; It's the first part of the returned value from getBase64 `"data:application/pdf;base64"`
If I remove this from the base64 string I can send an email to myself.

So the question is, why is this first part of the string there and how do I strip it out when the return value from getBase64 is an unknown type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a separate function to get the base64 encoding of the file using promises, then use the split function to remove that first part.

```
<input name="attachments" type="file" (change)="addattachment($event)" >

function getBase64(file, onLoadCallback) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function() { resolve(reader.result); };
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

async addattachment (event) {
    const myfile = event.target.files[0]
    const promise = this.getBase64(myfile)
    const base64file = await promise
    var ms_base64file = base64file.split(',')[1]
    console.log(ms_base64file)
}
```